# MySQL - RANGE CONDITION and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by

In the "High Performance MySQL" book says,

> The ORDER BY clause also has the same limitation as lookup queries: it needs to form a leftmost prefix of the index. In all other cases, MySQL uses a filesort.

And here is a table has an index on (rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id):

```
CREATE TABLE rental (
...
PRIMARY KEY (rental_id),
UNIQUE KEY rental_date (rental_date,inventory_id,customer_id),
KEY idx_fk_inventory_id (inventory_id),
KEY idx_fk_customer_id (customer_id),
KEY idx_fk_staff_id (staff_id),
...
);
```

> MySQL uses the rental_date index to order the following query, as you
>   can see from the lack of a filesort in EXPLAIN:

```
> mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT
> rental_id, staff_id FROM sakila.rental
> -> WHERE rental_date = '2005-05-25'
> -> ORDER BY inventory_id, customer_id\G
> *************************** 1. row *************************** 
> type: ref 
> possible_keys: rental_date 
> key: rental_date 
> rows: 1 
> Extra: Using where
```

> This works, even though the ORDER BY clause isn’t itself a leftmost
>   prefix of the index, because we specified an equality condition for
>   the first column in the index.

And

> This query has range condition on the first column, so MySQL doesn't
>   use the rest of index:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT `rental_id`, `staff_id` FROM `sakila`.`rental`
WHERE `rental_date` > '2005-05-25'
ORDER BY `inventory_id`, `customer_id`;
*************************** 1. row *************************** 
...
key: NULL Extra: Using where; using filesort
...
```

**Question: Why query has range condition on the first column, MySQL doesn't use the index?**

The first position that matches 'rental_date' > '2005-05-25' would be found using B-tree index. Then MySQL could scan sub nodes(inventory_id, customer_id) in sequence, I think. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that the index is like this:

```
rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id
======================================
...
2005-05-25, 10, 10
2005-05-25, 20, 20
2005-05-25, 30, 30
2005-05-26, 20, 20
2005-05-26, 40, 40
2005-05-27, 10, 10
2005-05-27, 30, 30
...
```

In the first query mysql uses the index to find first entry '2005-05-25'. Since `rental_date` is the first field of the index, the other fields (`inventory_id`, `customer_id`) for the same date value are in sorted order.

But in the second query imagine what happens with `2005-05-26`, `2005-05-27`. Suddenly, the `inventory_id`, `customer_id` are not sorted. They are sorted only for specific `rental_date` values. So mysql has to sort them finally.